# How can I display both Button and Button Name in Listbox Item from Code behind?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, listbox

Hi I have the following code , which assign a list of custom radio buttons to my List Box.

```
List<RadioButton> listUserControlBtns = new List<RadioButton>();

CustomLocalFolderButton btnLocalFolder = new CustomLocalFolderButton ();
CustomLocalFolderButton btnPlayListFolder = new CustomLocalFolderButton ();
CustomVideoButton btnVideoFolder = new CustomVideoButton ();
CutsomAudioButton btnMusicFolder = new CutsomAudioButton ();
CustomImageButton btnImageFolder = new CustomImageButton ();
ListUserControlBtns.Add(btnLocalFolder);

ListUserControlBtns.Add(btnPlayListFolder);
ListUserControlBtns.Add(btnVideoFolder);
ListUserControlBtns.Add(btnMusicFolder);
ListUserControlBtns.Add(btnImageFolder);

listMainFolder.ItemsSource = listUserControlBtns;
```

Now . I am able to display the radio buttons inside the listbox but also I want to display the name of the radiobutton below the radiobutton itself.This should happen for all the radiobuttons inside the listbox.

I dont want to use binding in XAML . Your suggestions and solutions  will help me in a great way.

The custom Radiobutoons class looks like below:

```
namespace customAudioButton
{
    public class CutsomAudioButton:RadioButton
    {
        public CutsomAudioButton()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CutsomAudioButton);
        }
    }
```

}

Also my generic XAML looks like following:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:customImageButton">


    <Style TargetType="local:CutsomAudioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CutsomAudioButton">
                    <Grid Width="200" Margin="0,0,0,19">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas_Copy2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="path3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">

                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas_Copy2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="path3_Copy" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>


                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Path x:Name="path1" Stroke="#FF844B08" Width="Auto" Data="F1M12,1.087C12,1.087 28.814,1.087 49.294,1.087 53.671,1.087 58.215,13 62.799,13 91.625,13 122,13 122,13 127.523,13 132,17.477 132,23 132,23 132,98 132,98 132,103.523 127.523,108 122,108 122,108 12,108 12,108 6.477,108 2,103.523 2,98 2,98 2,12.337 2,12.337 2,6.815 6.477,1.087 12,1.087z" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,1.765,-17.564,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="108.5" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5B802" Offset="0.996"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3EFDE"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBF9A05" Offset="0.065"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <Path x:Name="path1_Copy" Stroke="#FF844B08" Width="Auto" Data="F1 M120.50496,0.50000012 C126.02796,0.50000012 130.50496,4.9769998 130.50496,10.5 C130.50496,10.5 130.50496,85.355896 130.50496,85.355896 C130.50496,90.878891 126.02796,95.355896 120.50496,95.355896 C120.50496,95.355896 10.504963,95.355896 10.504963,95.355896 C4.9819636,95.355896 0.5049634,90.878891 0.5049634,85.355896 C0.5049634,85.355896 0.5049634,12.040168 0.5049634,12.040168 C0.33018857,5.8202529 4.7881746,0.99969035 11.184806,0.94185221 C39.903023,0.68218291 120.50496,0.50000012 120.50496,0.50000012 z" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11.497,14.41,-17.502,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="95.856" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5B802" Offset="0.996"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFADC5E" Offset="0.007"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE2BC22" Offset="0.166"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA16908" Offset="0.948"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                       <Canvas x:Name="canvas_Copy2" Margin="57.333,46.833,14.667,14.167" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" >
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="34.232"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_7" Width="53" Height="49" Data="F1M4.253,1.753C4.253,1.753 48.829,1.753 48.829,1.753 50.486,1.753 51.829,3.096 51.829,4.753 51.829,4.753 51.829,44.314 51.829,44.314 51.829,45.971 50.486,47.314 48.829,47.314 48.829,47.314 4.253,47.314 4.253,47.314 2.597,47.314 1.253,45.971 1.253,44.314 1.253,44.314 1.253,4.753 1.253,4.753 1.253,3.096 2.597,1.753 4.253,1.753z" Fill="White" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_8_copy3" Width="49" Height="40" Data="F1M4.252,1.795C4.252,1.795 44.832,1.795 44.832,1.795 46.34,1.795 47.563,3.017 47.563,4.526 47.563,4.526 47.432,38.028 47.432,38.028 47.432,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.521,4.526 1.521,4.526 1.521,3.017 2.743,1.795 4.252,1.795z" Fill="#FFDC0C6F" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="2"/>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_8" Width="27" Height="20" Data="F1M4.2,17.8C4.2,17.8 1.2,5.6 6.8,6 6.8,6 10,6.6 10,6.6 10,6.6 9.2,5 11.8,4 11.8,4 16.2,1.6 17.4,5.4 17.4,5.4 19.4,5.8 19.4,5.8 19.4,5.8 20.8,1.6 23.8,4.6 23.8,4.6 25.6,5.8 25.6,5.8 25.6,5.8 26,18.4 26,18.4 26,18.4 4.2,17.8 4.2,17.8z" Opacity="0.895" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="12">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                           <Path x:Name="Shape_9" Width="49" Height="22" Data="F1M1.8,20.8C1.8,20.8 47.8,20.6 47.8,20.6 47.8,20.6 47.8,7.4 47.8,7.4 47.8,7.4 26.8,2 1.2,14.2 1.2,14.2 1.2,20.8 1.2,20.8 1.2,20.8 1.8,20.8 1.8,20.8z" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="20">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1BD3D8" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0E5759" Offset="0.996"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                        </Canvas>
                        <Path x:Name="path3" Stroke="#FF844B08" Width="133" Data="F1M12,1.087C12,1.087 28.814,1.087 49.294,1.087 53.671,1.087 58.215,13 62.799,13 91.625,13 122,13 122,13 127.523,13 132,17.477 132,23 132,23 132,98 132,98 132,103.523 127.523,108 122,108 122,108 12,108 12,108 6.477,108 2,103.523 2,98 2,98 2,12.337 2,12.337 2,6.815 6.477,1.087 12,1.087z" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,1.719,-18,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="108.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Opacity="0">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6A5603" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3EFDE"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDAB20D" Offset="0.349"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <Canvas x:Name="canvas_Copy" Margin="0,8.333,7.667,52.667" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="53">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="34.232"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_4" Width="53" Height="49" Data="F1M4.253,1.753C4.253,1.753 48.829,1.753 48.829,1.753 50.486,1.753 51.829,3.096 51.829,4.753 51.829,4.753 51.829,44.314 51.829,44.314 51.829,45.971 50.486,47.314 48.829,47.314 48.829,47.314 4.253,47.314 4.253,47.314 2.597,47.314 1.253,45.971 1.253,44.314 1.253,44.314 1.253,4.753 1.253,4.753 1.253,3.096 2.597,1.753 4.253,1.753z" Fill="White" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_8_copy2" Width="49" Height="40" Data="F1M4.252,1.795C4.252,1.795 44.832,1.795 44.832,1.795 46.34,1.795 47.563,3.017 47.563,4.526 47.563,4.526 47.432,38.028 47.432,38.028 47.432,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.521,4.526 1.521,4.526 1.521,3.017 2.743,1.795 4.252,1.795z" Fill="#FFDC0C6F" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="2"/>
                           <Path x:Name="Shape_6" Width="49" Height="22" Data="F1M1.8,20.8C1.8,20.8 47.8,20.6 47.8,20.6 47.8,20.6 47.8,7.4 47.8,7.4 47.8,7.4 26.8,2 1.2,14.2 1.2,14.2 1.2,20.8 1.2,20.8 1.2,20.8 1.8,20.8 1.8,20.8z" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="20">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1BD3D8" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0E5759" Offset="0.996"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                        </Canvas>
                        <Path x:Name="path4" Width="154.261" Data="F1 M37.066082,0.5 C37.066082,0.5 143.61697,0.5 143.61697,0.5 C149.13997,0.5 154.73392,5.6793203 153.61697,10.5 C153.61697,10.5 133.61697,55.5 133.61697,55.5 C133.61697,55.5 128.07298,67.252579 127.88042,66.737434 C127.88042,66.737434 13.617228,66.737434 13.617228,66.737434 C9.6519403,66.778893 3.0821178,65.676422 0.5,58.919891 C0.5,58.919891 23.617235,10.5 23.617235,10.5 C26.732969,3.0064244 31.543129,0.5 37.066082,0.5 z" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,43.59,-41.214,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="67.254" UseLayoutRounding="False" Stroke="#FF844B08" Opacity="0">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5B802" Offset="0.684"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAD336" Offset="0.378"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA16908" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                       <Canvas x:Name="canvas_Copy1" Margin="0,8.333,7.667,52.667" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="53">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="34.232"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_1" Width="53" Height="49" Data="F1M4.253,1.753C4.253,1.753 48.829,1.753 48.829,1.753 50.486,1.753 51.829,3.096 51.829,4.753 51.829,4.753 51.829,44.314 51.829,44.314 51.829,45.971 50.486,47.314 48.829,47.314 48.829,47.314 4.253,47.314 4.253,47.314 2.597,47.314 1.253,45.971 1.253,44.314 1.253,44.314 1.253,4.753 1.253,4.753 1.253,3.096 2.597,1.753 4.253,1.753z" Fill="White" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_8_copy1" Width="49" Height="40" Data="F1M4.252,1.795C4.252,1.795 44.832,1.795 44.832,1.795 46.34,1.795 47.563,3.017 47.563,4.526 47.563,4.526 47.432,38.028 47.432,38.028 47.432,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.452,38.028 1.521,4.526 1.521,4.526 1.521,3.017 2.743,1.795 4.252,1.795z" Fill="#FFDC0C6F" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="2"/>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_2" Width="27" Height="20" Data="F1M4.2,17.8C4.2,17.8 1.2,5.6 6.8,6 6.8,6 10,6.6 10,6.6 10,6.6 9.2,5 11.8,4 11.8,4 16.2,1.6 17.4,5.4 17.4,5.4 19.4,5.8 19.4,5.8 19.4,5.8 20.8,1.6 23.8,4.6 23.8,4.6 25.6,5.8 25.6,5.8 25.6,5.8 26,18.4 26,18.4 26,18.4 4.2,17.8 4.2,17.8z" Opacity="0.895" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="12">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_10_copy1" Width="20" Height="14" Data="F1M3.925,11.948C3.925,11.948 1.925,3.816 5.658,4.083 5.658,4.083 7.791,4.483 7.791,4.483 7.791,4.483 7.258,3.416 8.991,2.75 8.991,2.75 11.923,1.15 12.723,3.683 12.723,3.683 14.056,3.95 14.056,3.95 14.056,3.95 14.989,1.15 16.989,3.15 16.989,3.15 18.189,3.95 18.189,3.95 18.189,3.95 18.455,12.348 18.455,12.348 18.455,12.348 3.925,11.948 3.925,11.948z" Opacity="0.815" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Top="22">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                            <Path x:Name="Shape_3" Width="49" Height="22" Data="F1M1.8,20.8C1.8,20.8 47.8,20.6 47.8,20.6 47.8,20.6 47.8,7.4 47.8,7.4 47.8,7.4 26.8,2 1.2,14.2 1.2,14.2 1.2,20.8 1.2,20.8 1.2,20.8 1.8,20.8 1.8,20.8z" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="20">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1BD3D8" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0E5759" Offset="0.996"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                        </Canvas>
                        <Path x:Name="path4_Copy" Width="154.261" Data="F1 M37.066082,0.5 C37.066082,0.5 143.61697,0.5 143.61697,0.5 C149.13997,0.5 154.73392,5.6793203 153.61697,10.5 C153.61697,10.5 133.61697,55.5 133.61697,55.5 C133.61697,55.5 128.07298,67.252579 127.88042,66.737434 C127.88042,66.737434 13.617228,66.737434 13.617228,66.737434 C9.6519403,66.778893 3.0821178,65.676422 0.5,58.919891 C0.5,58.919891 23.617235,10.5 23.617235,10.5 C26.732969,3.0064244 31.543129,0.5 37.066082,0.5 z" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,43.59,-41.214,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="67.254" UseLayoutRounding="False" Stroke="#FF844B08" Opacity="0">
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5B802" Offset="0.684"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAD336" Offset="0.378"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA16908" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <Border x:Name="border" Margin="-8,-14,-61,-15" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="#FFC20050" BorderThickness="5,5,6,5" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thanks,
Subhen

Comment: .NET conventions have type names begin with a capital letter you might want to consider follow the same conventions.  This convention is so common (not limited to .NET) that stackoverflow's syntax highlighter uses it to help users distinguish variables from type names.

Comment: It would help if you indicated in what way you have modified RadioButton with your custom classes.  In particular whether you have replaced the default template style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your custom `RadioButtons` have either not replaced the `DefaultStyleKey` or if you have your new template still contains a `ContentPresenter` with its `Content` property bound with "{TemplateBinding Content}".  Then:-

```
List<RadioButton> listUserControlBtns = new List<RadioButton>(); 

var btnLocalFolder = new CustomLocalFolderButton() {Content = "Label 1"}; 
var btnPlayListFolder = new CustomLocalFolderButton() {Content = "Label 2"};  
var btnVideoFolder = new CustomVideoButton() {Content = "Label 3"}; 
var btnMusicFolder = new CutsomAudioButton() {Content = "Label 4"}; 
var btnImageFolder = new CustomImageButton()  {Content = "Label 5"}; 

listUserControlBtns.Add(btnLocalFolder);  
listUserControlBtns.Add(btnPlayListFolder); 
listUserControlBtns.Add(btnVideoFolder); 
listUserControlBtns.Add(btnMusicFolder); 
listUserControlBtns.Add(btnImageFolder); 

listMainFolder.ItemsSource = listUserControlBtns;
```

**Edit**:

A sketchy outline of what you would need to do restore a content presenter to your Template for the custom controls:-

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomLocalFolderButton">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>  <!-- May need a specific size -->
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <!-- Your existing set of visual state groups here -->
    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <!-- Your existing UI for this control -->
    <ContentPresenter
      Grid.Column="1"
      x:Name="contentPresenter"
      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, 
I have replaced the DefaultStyle key  and not sure how to go about ContentPrsenter. Could you plz explain?

Comment: @Subhen:  Added example of using ContentPresenter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the content property of the buttons to display some text adjacent to them.